# Проверка выполнил ли пользователь действие в соцсети

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

на сайте есть кнопка "подпишитесь чтобы скачать", (для ютуба, твитера и фейсбука) при нажатии на нее должна открываться доп. вкладка с соцсетью где пользователь должен выполнить действие, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Скорее всего, на серверной части, надо написать парсер социальной сети, который будет проверять на выполнение действия. Если у социальной сети нету API для этого

Comment: API социальных сетей смотрите.

Comment: А можно как-то без api чтобы не нужно было авторизироваться пользователю в приложении

Comment: Это сейчас такая шутка была остроумная? подписаться на твою страницу не логинясь?

Comment: Нет, при использование api кога создаешь приложение, там вылазит окно потом типо разрешить приложению получать имя пользователя итд, а мне нужно без этого, чтобы просто окрывалась в новом окне соц сеть со страницой на которую нужно подписаться и если пользователь подписывается, она закрывается и на сайте происходит действие

Comment: ну, сами рисуйте тогда фрейм.

Comment: Никак нормально вы это не сделаете. Или через костыли (парсить соцсеть) или никак. Лучше используйте АПИ соцсетей.